# Dygraphs defaults to wrong valueRange using a linear scale

Tags: javascript, graph, range, axis, dygraphs

I have some temperature data I want to graph using dygraphs in JavaScript.

```
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
            chartdata, //js array containing the x and y values in js arrays according to http://dygraphs.com/data.html
            {
                labels: labels, //x and y label(s) in js array
                title: 'Weatherstation',
                legend: 'always',
                labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
                showRangeSelector: true,
                rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
                //valueRange: [-5, 25]
            });
```

The temperatures range from about -1.7°C to about 24°C and the data contains gaps. According to dygraphs' reference the default valueRange (y axis scale) is this:

> valueRange
>   Default: Full range of the input is shown

The resulting graph has a y-axis-range of about -0.7°C to 5°C though.
[image: Graph with default (dynamic) valueRange]

*Apparently I cannot show you a screenshot of the manually ranged version due to my low rep*

A workaround is setting valueRange manually, but then the y-axis-range won't dynamically adapt to the x-axis-range selected.
You can see all readings above 0°C in the range selector below the actual graph. I can even see the > 5°C values in the legend when I hover above that x-range and the scale adapts, when I select a small range with only high y values.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
A possibility to show negative parts of the graph in the rangeselector would be nice, too. So if someone knows a solution for that, please tell me.

I found a similar unanswered bugreport for a R package that generates dygraphs from R data, but they didn't have a solution either:
https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/32

Comment: BTW, I am open to dygraphs alternatives. I need multiple lines (temperature, pressure, etc), a rather simple rangeselector and a legend that displays the values when I hover over the graph. The data has gaps, so the graph should be able to display those.

Comment: dygraphs should behave in the way you want. It's hard to debug without a reproducible example. Please add one to the question, either via SO's built-in snippets or dygraphs.com/fiddle.

Comment: A couple thoughts: 1) the values in chartdata are strings, not numbers (`"3.95"` instead of 3.95). This might be throwing things off. 2) there could be a bug with `rangeSelectorHeight`. Try removing that option.

Comment: @danvk Thanks, parsing the strings as float solved my problem. I was mislead by the documentation stating `If your y-values are just numbers, then they need to be parseable by JavaScript's parseFloat function` which only refered to csv data. Removing `rangeSelectorHeight` didn't fix the selector only showing positive values through.

Comment: @danvk I have to correct the last bit, removing `rangeSelectorHeight` fixed that problem, too!